# Search non partition key in Azure Storage table

Tags: azure-storage

Just wondering whether it is possible to search non-partition key from Azure storage table.

I am using following link to access records. But there always have to give `PartitionKey` and `RowKey`

[Access Azure Storage](https://windowsfanblog.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/a-generic-class-to-access-azure-table-storage/)

In case if I have a other column value in the table apart from `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` how should I do that?

Comment: it seems to me that you can simply create the filter in anyway you want see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can search any properties by using below query:

```
TableQuery<myEntity> query = new TableQuery<myEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("columne_name", QueryComparisons.Equal, "column_value"));
```

[GenerateFilterCondition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablequery.generatefiltercondition.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) doesn't require you to search through partitionkey or rowkey, you can search any properties you want.